# Como verificar Recaptcha de Google usando PHP

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

Tengo un formulario de contacto, que, si envía el correo sin embargo no logro hacer que funcione con el recaptcha de Google, he intentado algunas maneras viendo ejemplos, pero soy nuevo para PHP.

Mi consulta como adicionar ello del recaptcha para que se validado. El código utilizado es el siguiente, si me ayudan comentando como adicionar ello por favor.

```
<?php

if ($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] == '') {
        echo "Recaptcha no validado";
} else {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->secret = "aqui es clave secreta";
    $obj->response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $obj->remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($obj)
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    
    $validar = json_decode($result);
    
    /* FIN DE CAPTCHA */
    
    if ($validar->success) {
    
        $nombre = utf8_decode($_POST['nombre']);
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $telefono = utf8_decode($_POST['telefono']);
        $asunto = utf8_decode($_POST['asunto']);
        $mensaje = utf8_decode($_POST['mensaje']);
        
        $para = "correo@correo.com";//Email al que se enviar
        $asunto = utf8_decode("Seccion Contactanos");//Puedes cambiar el asunto del mensaje desde aqui
        
        $consulta = "
                    <h3>Seccion Contactanos en Servcom-it.com</h3>
                    <strong>Nombre:</strong> $nombre
                    <br>
                    <strong>E-mail:</strong> $email
                    <br>
                    <strong>Telefono:</strong> $telefono
                    <br>
                    <strong>Asunto:</strong> $asunto
                    <br>
                    <strong>Mensaje:</strong> $mensaje
                    ";
        
        $headers = "From: $nombre <$email>\r\n"; //Quien envia?
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP5\n";
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        
        mail($para, $asunto, $consulta, $headers);
    } else {
        echo "Recaptcha no validado";
    }
}
?>
```

**Formulario**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="resultado"></div><!--aquí se va a mostrar mi primer valor-->

    <form action="contact.php" method=post name="formx" id="datos">
        <table width="450px">
        <tr>
        <td valign="top">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" maxlength="50" size="30">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign="top">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
        <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
        </td>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
            <label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
            <input type="text" name="telefono" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
            <label for="asunto">Asunto</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
            <input type="text" name="asunto" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign="top">
        <label for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
        <textarea name="mensaje" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="resultado">
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="Aqui_la_clave"></div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo más que e logrado hacer que se muestre es en un alert hehe. Si no me equivoco se necesita de Ajax, soy malo en ello.

Answer (score 0):

Después de validar en el lado del servidor debes llamar la api de recaptcha, si la respuesta de recaptcha es true, entonces proceder con el envío

```html
//HTML
    <head>
    <script async src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    </head>
    <form action="#sample" method="post">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="Clave del sitio"></div>
    <input name="datos" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    //PHP
    <?php
        $datos;$captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['datos'])){ 
           $datos = $_POST['datos'];}   
        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
           $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];}
        if(!$captcha){
           echo 'Chequea la Captcha';}
        $secretKey = "Clave secreta";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        //Chequear captcha con Google
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
           echo '<h4>Error!</h4>';
            } else {
        //si la captcha es correcta se escribe los datos introducidos
           echo '<div id="result">'.$datos.'</div>';}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo con PHP, no es obligatorio usar AJAX para verificar el captcha, aunque si más profesional si lo usaras, con AJAX quedaría dinámico y podrías actualizar tu captcha en cada fallo.

Lo que modifique respecto a tu código fue esta parte:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->secret = "aqui es clave secreta";
$obj->response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$obj->remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

por:

```
$data = array(
    'secret' => 'pon_tu_secret_key',
    'response' => $recaptcha,
    'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
);
```

En mi ejemplo recuerda poner tu **site_key** y tu **secret_key**.

**Posible ejemplo:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ejemplo reCAPTCHA 2.0 con PHP</title>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="contact.php" method="post">
            <input name="name" placeholder="Nombre"/>
           
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="tu_site_key"></div>

            <button type="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**contact.php**

```
<?php
    // Obtener datos formulario
    $name = $_POST["name"] ?? ''; 
    // Obtenienes captcha
    $recaptcha = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"] ?? '';
    
    // Configuracion Captcha
    //
    // Url para la verificacion
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    
    // Datos para http_build_query()
    $data = array(
        'secret' => 'tu_secret_key', // tu secret key
        'response' => $recaptcha,
        'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    );
    
    // Options 
    $options = array(
            'http' => array (
                'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
        );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    // Resultado Captcha.
    $resultado = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    // Comprobar resultado
    $verify = json_decode($resultado);

    // Captche is true
    if ($verify->success) {
        // No eres un robot, continuamos con el envío del email
        // ...
        // ...
        echo 'Captcha es valido';
    } else {
        // Eres un robot!
        echo 'Eres un Robot';
    }
?>
```